# Cannot read property 'items' of null

Tags: angular, typescript

Here, x is not being able to access the properties of ShoppingCart the error it shows is Property item does not exist on type {} I dont know where is mistake i have made which i am not being able to identified

shopping-cart.ts

```
import { ShoppingCartItem } from './shopping-cart-item';
import { Product } from './product';

export class ShoppingCart {
    items: ShoppingCartItem[] = [];

}
```

shopping-cart-service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/observable';
import { Product } from './models/product';
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { ShoppingCart } from './models/shopping-cart';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ShoppingCartService {
  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }
async getCart(): Promise<Observable<ShoppingCart>> {
    const cartId = await this.getOrCreateCartId();
    return this.db.object('/shopping-carts/' + cartId).valueChanges()
      .pipe(map(x => new ShoppingCart(x.items)));
  }

}
```

Comment: Can console.log(x) inside the map function so that we know the exact object structure you got returned?

Comment: why do you encapsulate Observable into Promise `Promise<Observable<ShoppingCart>>`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem, if I understand your question correctly, is that you are creating a new instance of ShoppingCart in your pipe method. However, you are sending x.items as parameters to the ShoppingCart class, but that class is missing a constructor of how to process the parameters. Therefore, ShoppingCart.items will always be any empty array as long as you don't manually assign it. Assuming x is some data from an API and that x has property items.

Try with this:

```
export class ShoppingCart {
  items: ShoppingCartItem[] = [];

  constructor(data?: Partial<ShoppingCart>) {
    Object.assign(this, data);
  }
}
```

And:

```
return this.db.object('/shopping-carts/' + cartId).valueChanges()
  .pipe(map(x => new ShoppingCart(x)));
```

Now x.items will be mapped to ShoppingCart.items.

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner way of doing this would be,

shopping-cart.ts

```
export interface IShoppingCartList {
  items: ShoppingCartItem[];
}

export class ShoppingCart implements IShoppingCartList {
  constructor(public items: ShoppingCartItem[]) { }
}

export class ShoppingCartItem {
  x: string;
  y: number;
}
```

shopping-cart-service.ts

```
import { ShoppingCart } from './model/shopping-cart';

new ShoppingCart([{ x: 'Hi', y: 56 }])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just fetch the values from items and pass whole object.

```
return this.db.object('/shopping-carts/' + cartId +'/items').valueChanges()
      .pipe(map(x => new ShoppingCart(x)) .
```